# Angular material textarea not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a simple login form in angular 10 using angular material.
I have add angular to my project successfully. I tried to create a simple text area for email and password,the text area is displayed as box I tried a lot but unable to remove this box shape. I am expecting this.
[image]

but i am getting this instead

[image]

This is my html

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput rows="5"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

this is my css

```
mat-card{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

mat-form-field,
textarea{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it seems like angular material is not recognized. can you confirm it's properly installed ?

Comment: Have you imported relevant material modules? https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

Comment: @ihorbond,@Prabh its installed and mat card is working as expected,only this test area is not working.

Comment: see your styles.css and check if you has,e.g. a `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`